# Prove the following recurrence relation for the Hadamard matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am to show that the following gives a Hadamard matrix with dimension $2^k$ for $k = 0,1,2,3,\dots$, if
$H_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix}$, then $$H_{k+1} = \begin{bmatrix}H_k & H_k \\ H_k & -H_k \end{bmatrix}.$$
I am having trouble on where to start and how to prove this. Could I please have some help?

Thanks

Comment: You need to show $HH^{T}=n I_n$ where $n=2^{k}$ ... and this is easily done by induction.

Comment: In other words, the definition of Hadamard matrix is your friend.  One part of that definition is easy, the other is a minor computation.